# what is the right way to install docker and use it on VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

One month ago I used following ways to use docker engined jupyter out of problem(https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker):

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter

docker run --runtime=nvidia --name tensorflow1 -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

but now I fond it impossible. I can't open jupyter with http://[external address]:8888

I tried the following method and can't succeed:

```
docker run —runtime=nvdidia -d -p 6006:6006 —name web nginx
```

Did google make some changes recently?Can anyone give me the recent manual or guide I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explore a bit about Google cloud Kubernates engine, Cloud Build, Image repository in Google cloud platform.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/